Puppet Enterprise - Code Manager - ERROR -> :branch: "production" === :branch does not return true
Solved from thread Puppet Code Manager setup issue with Bitbucket
But I will still post perhaps someone else faces the same issue.
Had to run :
runuser -u pe-puppet -- /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/r10k -c /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/code-manager/r10k.yaml deploy environment production --puppetfile 


and
runuser -u pe-puppet -- /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/r10k -c /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/code-manager/r10k.yaml deploy environment production --puppetfile


This is the original post :
I have installed Puppet Enterprise version 2023.6.0.24 on Alma 9.3.
I am following the tutorial at https://www.puppet.com/docs/pe/2023.6/code_mgr_config#code_mgr_enable for enabling external repo on Code Manager.
I did these steps :

created  /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ssh/id-control_repo.ed25519 and /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ssh/id-control_repo.ed25519.pub files , and are owned by pe-puppet
added them .pub contents to my github SSH keys .
the repo is at git@github.com:cozsmin/puppet_control-repo00.git ( I made it public but still I need the private key in order to get a clone ... )

For the puppet_enterprise::profile::master class :

set 'code_manager_auto_configure' to 'true'.
set 'r10k_remote' set to 'git@github.com:cozsmin/puppet_control-repo00.git'
set 'r10k_private_key' = '/etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ssh/id-control_repo.ed25519'
set 'r10k_known_hosts' = [{"name":"github.com","type":"ssh-ed25519","key":"AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIOMqqnkVzrm0SdG6UOoqKLsabgH5C9okWi0dh2l9GKJl"}]
committed the changes

Created a puppet user and added him to the 'code deployers' group
Executed : puppet-access login --lifetime 180d
The git repo has 2 branches , "production" and "deployment00" . "production" is the main one.
Files in "production" branch are :
Puppetfile:
mod 'mod00',
    :git => 'git@github.com:cozsmin/puppet_control-repo00.git',
    :branch => 'production'

environment.conf:
modulepath=site-modules:modules:$basemodulepath

Files in "deployment00" branch are :
Puppetfile:
mod 'mod00',
    :git => 'git@github.com:cozsmin/puppet_control-repo00.git',
    :branch => 'deployment00'

environment.conf:
modulepath=site-modules:modules:$basemodulepath

I have executed "puppet-code deploy --dry-run" and the output was OK :
[root@PuppetEnterprise ~]#  puppet-code deploy --dry-run
--dry-run implies --all.
--dry-run implies --wait.
Dry-run deploying all environments.
Found 0 environments.
Found 2 environments.
[
  {
    "environment": "deployment00"
  },
  {
    "environment": "production"
  }
]
[root@PuppetEnterprise ~]#

However running 'puppet-code deploy deployment00 --wait' shows this error :
[root@PuppetEnterprise ~]# puppet-code deploy deployment00 --wait
Found 0 environments.
Found 1 environments.
[
  {
    "environment": "deployment00",
    "error": {
      "details": {
        "corrected-name": "deployment00"
      },
      "kind": "puppetlabs.code-manager/deploy-failure",
      "msg": "Errors while deploying environment 'deployment00' (exit code: 1):\nERROR\t -> :branch: \"production\" === :branch does not return true\n"
    },
    "id": 1,
    "status": "failed"
  }
]
[root@PuppetEnterprise ~]#

Do you know what should I do ?
Configuring Code Manager
